# How to remove parent element of each collection and represent it as array in json

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, json.net

I have the following XML:

```
<Envelops
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <BusinessPartners>
        <CardCode>L10002</CardCode>
        <BPAddresses>
            <row>
                <AddressName>Bill To</AddressName>
                <AddressType>bo_BillTo</AddressType>
                <BPCode>L10002</BPCode>
                <U_WBCUSTADDID>84</U_WBCUSTADDID>
                <RowNum>0</RowNum>
            </row>
        </BPAddresses>
        <U_WBCUSTID>74</U_WBCUSTID>
        <UploadURL>BusinessPartners('L10002')</UploadURL>
    </BusinessPartners>
</Envelops>
```

I am using Json.Net with the following code for serialization to JSON:

```
foreach (XmlNode data2 in d1.GetElementsByTagName("BusinessPartners"))
{
    var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(data2, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented, true);            
}
```

I am getting the JSON format below:

```
{
  "CardCode": "L10002",
  "BPAddresses": {
    "row": {
      "AddressName": "Bill To",
      "AddressType": "bo_BillTo",
      "BPCode": "L10002",
      "U_WBCUSTADDID": "84",
      "RowNum": "0"
    }
  },
  "U_WBCUSTID": "74",
  "UploadURL": "BusinessPartners('L10002')"
}
```

What I would like to achieve is this format instead:

```
{
  "CardCode": "L10002",
  "BPAddresses": [{
      "AddressName": "Bill To",
      "AddressType": "bo_BillTo",
      "BPCode": "L10002",
      "U_WBCUSTADDID": "84",
      "RowNum": "0"
    }],
  "U_WBCUSTID": "74",
  "UploadURL": "BusinessPartners('L10002')"
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do some manipulation on the XML prior to using `SerializeXmlNode` in order to get the result you want.

1. Add a `json:Array="true"` attribute to the `BPAddresses` element to signal Json.Net to treat that element as part of an array when converted to JSON.  (Note the `json:` attribute prefix corresponds to the `http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json` XML namespace.)
2. Move the children of the `row` element directly into `BPAddresses`.  If there's more than one `row`, then create additional `BPAddresses` elements as siblings of the original `BPAddresses` element for each row.  (Make sure each new `BPAddresses` element also has the `json:Array="true"` attribute.)

The code below should give you what you need:

```
foreach (XmlElement data2 in d1.GetElementsByTagName("BusinessPartners"))
{
    XmlElement bpa = (XmlElement)data2.SelectSingleNode("BPAddresses");
    XmlElement insertionPoint = bpa;

    foreach (XmlElement row in bpa.GetElementsByTagName("row"))
    {
        // Create a new BPAddresses element and add an Array="true" attribute to it 
        // so JSON.Net will know to treat it as an array
        XmlElement addr = d1.CreateElement("BPAddresses");
        XmlAttribute attr = d1.CreateAttribute("Array", "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json");
        attr.Value = "true";
        addr.Attributes.Append(attr);

        // move all the children of the row element into the new BPAddresses element
        foreach (XmlElement child in row.GetElementsByTagName("*").Cast<XmlElement>().ToList())
        {
            addr.AppendChild(child);
        }

        // insert the new element after the last BPAddresses element
        data2.InsertAfter(addr, insertionPoint);
        insertionPoint = addr;
    }

    // remove the original BPAddresses element (and its children)
    data2.RemoveChild(bpa);

    var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(data2, Formatting.Indented, true);
    Console.WriteLine(requestBody);
}
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ML0D6Z